# MySQL select followed by a subquery

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I have modified my question a little to make it clearer.

I found a strange `select` syntax [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/solution/#). It is a solution to [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/description/). The interesting code is

```
SELECT
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            Salary
        FROM
            Employee
        ORDER BY Salary DESC
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS SecondHighestSalary
;
```

`select` is followed by a subquery. Normally `select` should be followed by `column` name, as seen [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html). 
To better understand the usage of `select`, I tested in Chrome an example given here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all. The original `SQL` statement is 
 `SELECT customerId FROM Customers`. 
It returns `91` rows.

 I add an outer `select` to it: 
`select (SELECT customerId FROM Customers);` 
 It returns only one row: the first row. 
I do not understand why it only retrieves one row instead of all the `customerId`. 
 Can any one explain it? Thanks

Comment: limit 1  return a single row

Comment: `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1` - skip 1 top line (`OFFSET 1`), return 1 line (`LIMIT 1`)

Comment: I can understand the interesting code above, and the `limit` and `offset` meaning, but I cannot understand <br> 1. why `select` is followed by a `table` instead of `column` name, since subquery should return a table. <br> 2. why `select` only choose the first `row` in the example I test in Chrome.

Comment: In this instance the super query does nothing at all.

Comment: It does something. If you remove the outer `select`, then all the `customerId` are retrieved. There are total `91` `customerId`s

Comment: Nope. No customerids are returned, because none are selected

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried the `customerId` example I mentioned? There is a link and my test SQL statement in my question.

Comment: `select (SELECT customerId FROM Customers);` is not valid unless the table has at most one row, and then it's equivalent to having "a column" there (same as having any expression, e.g. a constant, there). Also that tool is not MySQL. If it does not return an error (which I doubt), the actual question would be: "Why does the tool on w3schools does not return an error?" - and it should be posted on the w3schools-forum as a bug. Also, add the actual query. It's a 2 liner, it won't even require more space than the vague "I (hope I correctly) added an outer select to some unspecified query".

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks. You are right. w3schools is not using `MySQL` in this example. I tested a similar example using `MySQL`. It output error unless the subquery returns only one row.<br> How can I mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the query with and without the superquery is that in the event that there are fewer than two rows, the subquery will return no result...

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(employee_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,salary INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES
(1,100);

 SELECT DISTINCT
             Salary
         FROM
             Employee
         ORDER BY Salary DESC
         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

 SELECT
     (SELECT DISTINCT
             Salary
         FROM
             Employee
         ORDER BY Salary DESC
         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS SecondHighestSalary
 ;
+---------------------+
| SecondHighestSalary |
+---------------------+
|                NULL |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can understand the example you gave here. The outer `select` makes a difference. My problem is: If the subquery return one column, multiple rows, then why the outer select only display the first row, as I mentioned in the customerId examples.

Comment: @nlite You're referring to an entirely different query that you haven't yet shared with us, so I don't see how we can help with that. Look carefully at my answer; it's very thorough, with no links to external information. See if you can amend your question accordingly.